# XML request is not being sent using wp_remote_post()

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

appologies in advance. I am trying to send XML request using wp_remote_post().

Im trying to send request to my SMS Provider to send one time OTP.

```
$url = "http://gate.payvand.tj/xml/";
$xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<request>
  <request-type>9</request-type>
  <terminal-id>".$termid."</terminal-id>
  <login>".$login."</login>
  <password-md5>".$pwd."</password-md5>
  <message txn-id=\"".$txn."\" sign=\"".$sign."\">
  <to>
    <source-address>".$source_address."</source-address>
    <destination-address>".$mobile_number."</destination-address>
    <data-encoding>1</data-encoding>
    <text>".$message."</text>
  </to>
  </message>
</request>";

$response = wp_remote_post(
$url,
array(
'method' => 'POST',
'timeout' => 45,
'redirection' => 5,
'httpversion' => '1.0',
'headers' => array(
    'Content-Type' => 'text/xml'
),
'body' => array('postdata' => $xml, 'postfield' => 'value'),
'sslverify' => false
)
);
```

My provider is not recieving this request.
But he is recieving and executing it like this

```
    $xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<request>
  <request-type>9</request-type>
  <terminal-id>".$termid."</terminal-id>
  <login>".$login."</login>
  <password-md5>".$pwd."</password-md5>
  <message txn-id=\"".$txn."\" sign=\"".$sign."\">
  <to>
    <source-address>".$source_address."</source-address>
    <destination-address>".$mobile_number."</destination-address>
    <data-encoding>1</data-encoding>
    <text>".$message."</text>
  </to>
  </message>
</request>";

$ch = curl_init();
$url = "http://gate.payvand.tj/xml/";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
```

Could you please explain the mistake in the first snippet?